# Why does this way of Deleting Repeated Elements in a Doubly Linked List not work?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I tried to delete repeated elements in a Doubly Linked List, using this logic
I'll create a temporary pointer that will traverse till the end of a linked list under a for loop till it reaches NULL. Under this for loop, I'll again traverse till the end of linked list, to search for repeated elements. If I find the element repeated I'll assign it to a variable called temporaryStorer, and then after changing the links, free the temporaryStorer

Why does this cause an error at the line:

```
(index->leftLink->rightLink)=(index->rightLink);
```

Here is the code

```
NODE* deleteDuplicates(NODE* head){
    NODE* current;
    NODE* temporaryStorer;
    NODE* index;
    if (head==NULL) {
        printf("List is empty\n");
        return head;
    } else {
        for (current=head; current!=NULL; current=current->rightLink) {
            for (index=current->rightLink; index!=NULL; index=index->rightLink) {
                if ((index->info)==(current->info)) {
                    //Values are equal
                    //Index is duplicate
                    temporaryStorer=index;
                    (index->leftLink->rightLink)=(index->rightLink);
                    if (index->rightLink!=NULL){
                        index->rightLink->leftLink=index->leftLink;
                        free(temporaryStorer);
                    }
                       
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    return head;
}
```

My Node is defined in this way

```
typedef struct NODE {
    struct NODE* leftLink;
    int info;
    struct NODE* rightLink;
    
}NODE;
```

The error I obtained says **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10)**

Comment: To me, this does not appear to be a simple linked list but rather a binary tree structure.

Comment: Run it in gdb, find the point that the error was thrown, and get a backtrace / point out that line. @500-InternalServerError They're using "leftlink" and "rightlink" as "previous" and "next" values respectively (so a Deque), it's still being treated as a linkedlist structure (in terms of what is currently given to us).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant not Linked List, but Doubly Linked List

Comment: What is `head`'s `leftlink`'s value?

Comment: When it crashes on this line, then `index->leftLink` will be `NULL`, as `index` cannot be `NULL` at that moment.

Comment: @Welbog I am setting head's Left Link as NULL

Comment: The crash message means you're running on MacOS, I believe, and that you're accessing `index->rightLink` (or perhaps `current->rightLink`) when `index` (or `current`) is NULL.  Note that the test for an empty list is not really needed unless you absolutely want the message printed — the outer `for` loop in the `else` block will simply not enter the loop if `head` is NULL when the function is called.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I ran it on Xcode. The thing is it works on the Online C Compilers, but doesn't seem to work on Xcode. Is it some fault with Online C Compiler or my code is actually wrong. That's what I am trying to figure out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inner for loop you have

```
for (index=current->rightLink; index!=NULL; index=index->rightLink) {
     if ((index->info)==(current->info)) {
        ...
        temporaryStorer=index;
        ...
        if (index->rightLink!=NULL){
               ...
               free(temporaryStorer);
        }
    }
}
```

So as `temporaryStorer` points to the same memory as `index` (and so doesn't serve any purpose in your code snippet) in fact you call `free(index)` and then you access it again by `index=index->rightLink`. That invokes Undefined behaviour